# Rewrite SQL subquery with ORDER ... LIMIT using JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL query that maps Users to Zones according to their location, and the zone boundaries:

```sql
UPDATE User u SET u.zoneId = (
   SELECT z.id FROM Zone z
   WHERE ST_Contains(z.boundary, u.location)
   ORDER BY z.level DESC
   LIMIT 1
);
```

This works fine, but it is quite slow as it's performing a subquery for every single record.

**Is it possible to rewrite it using a JOIN, even though it's using `ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1` in the subquery?**

This `ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1` is necessary as several encapsulated zones can match a location, and only the smallest one (highest level) must be assigned.

Comment: @user2864740 Can you develop..?

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure since it is an UPDATE - the sub-select is merely to pick the value.

Comment: 1.) I assume that ST_Contains(z.boundary, u.location) is a stored procedure. Would you please edit the query to break this out and make it visible to us all. 2.) Use EXPLAIN to get a sense of how the optimiser is handling your query.. you should always make use of EXPLAIN when building queries as the indexes you have, or not, can make a big difference to performance.

Comment: @Ian [ST_Contains](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/functions-for-testing-spatial-relations-between-geometric-objects.html#function_st-contains) is not a stored procedure, it's a GIS function that tells whether a geometry contains another.

Comment: The level is an issue. Without that you could just use UPDATE User u 
INNER JOIN Zone z
ON ST_Contains(z.boundary, u.location)
SET u.zoneId = z.id , but to take account of the level would seem to require a subquery on the updated table (something like UPDATE User u 
INNER JOIN Zone z
ON ST_Contains(z.boundary, u.location)
INNER JOIN
(
 SELECT u.id, MAX(z.level) AS MaxLevel
 FROM User u 
 INNER JOIN Zone z
 ON ST_Contains(z.boundary, u.location)
 GROUP BY u.id
) Sub1
ON u.id = Sub1.id AND z.level = Sub1.MaxLevel
SET u.zoneId = z.id) but that is not allowed in MySQL

Comment: @Benjamin Thanks. I haven't used MySql GIS function very often. In your query you have z.id and u.zoneId - are they equivalent? Can they be tied together by making the subquery reference the outer query? There is a niggle in MySql where you can't reference the UPDATE table in a first order subquery but if you nest it then you can. eg (SELECT ... FROM (SELECT ... WHERE u.zoneId = z.id) zz ... LIMIT 1 ) and so on. And don't forget to use EXPLAIN to show you how the query is being handled by the optimiser.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of any test data or full DDLs I can't really test this, but this might work. Using joins and a sub query, but burying the sub query an extra level down which might allow MySQL to ignore he use of the table to be updated in the sub query.

Does rely on the user table having a unique key ( I have just taken it as being called id ).

```
UPDATE User u 
INNER JOIN Zone z
ON ST_Contains(z.boundary, u.location)
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id, MaxLevel
    FROM
    (
        SELECT u.id, MAX(z.level) AS MaxLevel
        FROM User u 
        INNER JOIN Zone z
        ON ST_Contains(z.boundary, u.location)
        GROUP BY u.id
    ) Sub1
) Sub2
ON u.id = Sub2.id AND z.level = Sub2.MaxLevel
SET u.zoneId = z.id
```

If you could set up some test data in SQL fiddle I can test this.

Comment: Wouldn't that not be faster anyway? As there's still a subquery as far as I can see..!

Comment: Difference is your original query uses a correlated sub query, so for every row to be updated mysql is having to perform a select. Unless the number of records is pretty limited a correlated sub query is likely to perform badly.

Comment: Do you mean that yours would execute the subquery only once?

Comment: Yes, nothing in the sub query depends on the results of the outer query / the UPDATE. The sub query generates a set of data, and then joins this set of data against the tables in the UPDATE statement.

Comment: Interesting, I will take the time to set up some test data as soon as I can.

Comment: Let me know the results. The sub query gets the highest level for each user, and joins that back against zone to limit the boundaries for that particular user.